# Computer needs to "rest" after a power outage

Tags: power-supply, power

My PC normally runs fine.

After a power outage or a short-circuit, however, it can't be turned back on until some significant amount of time (>1 hour) passes. My case has LEDs that are on even when the PC is off, and they too are not lit until some time passes.

Other devices connected to the some power strip work fine after the outage.

What can be the cause of this issue, and is anything I can do to fix it? I suspect the PSU, a Seasonic M12II-750 Bronze 750W, but it would a shame to replace an otherwise-functioning expensive PSU just for these rare cases of an outage, so I'm asking here first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PSU is the most likely culprit, the second-most likely culprit is the motherboard. The third possibility is something funky happening with your home's wiring or some extension cord you may have between your computer and the power outlet (for now you might want to make sure that your case is connected directly to the wall socket if possible)

There's a plethora of things that could be going wrong, but I suspect faulty capacitors in the PSU that are taking this tremendous amount of time to charge themselves up to an operational state. I am working on the assumption here that all other electronics in your home work fine after power is restored.

You could as drspa44 recommended eliminate the power supply being at fault by testing it without being connected to this specific computer (you can connect it to another computer, or use the method he recommended) to simulate a power outage you cut off power to the PSU and then start the computer (or testing device) until the computer (or device) powers off completely (leds die) and the PSU is drained. After that it's just a matter of turning it back on (or plugging it in again) and seeing what happens.

What I personally would do is try using another power supply without specifically testing this one, if the same result happens the problem is very likely with your motherboard, or your home's wiring setup (if it is the latter you can simply try moving the computer to the other end of your house and see if it starts quicker there)

That's about all I can think of from the given information.

Answer (score 1):

If you unplug it from the power outlet overnight and plug it in the next morning, does it take an hour to be ready to boot again? If there is no issue doing that, I wouldn't blame the PSU. Perhaps there is an issue with your home's electricity after power cuts and the like.

If doing the above causes an issue, you may be able to eliminate the possibility that it is the motherboard at fault, by doing the paperclip test here: http://www.wikihow.com/Check-a-Power-Supply
If you can't start the PSU's fan with a paper clip, having not been connected to power for an hour, it most likely needs replacing.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue and the problem was CMOS battery - wrong contact. I know that CMOS should be for BIOS date/time only, but my computer really does not start without battery. So you can try it.